# UIViewContentMode Vs UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, uicontrol

I have UIButton, i want to align its imageView to left .
when i tried :
**self.cancelButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;**

it doesn't seem to work as imageView is still Coming at Center (UIViewContentModeCenter)

but when i use 
**self.cancelButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;**

it aligns the imageView perfectly . can some one explain to me why such behavior, as UIViewContentModeLeft should also work ?

Answer (score 0):

Any UIControl elements will use the **contentHorizontalAlignment** and **contentVerticalAlignment** properties to override the **contentMode** of their child UIViews and UIImageViews. The default contentHorizontalAlignment will override your contentMode until you have  explicitly set the button's contentHorizontalAlignment to what you want.